# Sequel: how to pass variable to select block?

Tags: ruby, sequel, sequel-gem

I need to calculate users count inside of select query.
Here is my SQL snippet

```
SELECT count(id) FROM demo.users WHERE year_id = 'c4c62a9d-801f-4573-92a8-aa0a8589200a'
```

I use it inside of

```
   CASE count(DISTINCT assigned_lessons.id)
     WHEN 0 THEN 0
     ELSE count(DISTINCT homework_results.id) :: float /
          (
            count(DISTINCT assigned_lessons.id) *
            (SELECT count(id) FROM demo.users WHERE year_id = 'c4c62a9d-801f-4573-92a8-aa0a8589200a')
          )
       END AS completed_homework_rate
```

Here is my implementation on Sequel which works

```
        Sequel.case({ 0 => 0 },
          Sequel.cast(count(:homework_results__id).distinct, :float) /
            (
              count(:assigned_lessons__id).distinct *
                DB['demo__users'.to_sym].select do
                  count(id)
                end.where(year_id: 'c4c62a9d-801f-4573-92a8-aa0a8589200a')
            ),
          count(:assigned_lessons__id).distinct,
        ).as(:completed_homework_rate),
```

but I need use something like this

```
        Sequel.case({ 0 => 0 },
          Sequel.cast(count(:homework_results__id).distinct, :float) /
            (
              count(:assigned_lessons__id).distinct *
                DB["#{schema}__users".to_sym].select do
                  count(id)
                end.where(year_id: year.id)
            ),
          count(:assigned_lessons__id).distinct,
        ).as(:completed_homework_rate),
```

I need to use `schema` and `year` varibale inside of with query but Sequel say me

```
undefined method `id' for #<Sequel::SQL::Identifier @value=>:year>
```

or if I pass year id directly as a string it replaces `schema` variable in the wrong way

```
SELECT count("id") FROM "#<Sequel::SQL::Identifier:0x00007f8d36b553b8>"."users"
```

Simplified use case

```
  DB[:curriculum_strands].select do
      [
        Sequel.case({ 0 => 0 },
          Sequel.cast(count(:homework_results__id).distinct, :float) /
            (
              count(:assigned_lessons__id).distinct *
                DB["#{schema}__users".to_sym].select do
                  count(id)
                end.where(year_id: year.id)
            ),
          count(:assigned_lessons__id).distinct,
        ).as(:completed_homework_rate),
      ]
    end.left_join(...)
```

Is any way to pass variables to the select block in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I don't need to use block it `select`.

Here is my solution

```
  DB[:curriculum_strands].select(
      completed_homework_rate.as(:completed_homework_rate),
    ).left_join(...)

private

def completed_homework_rate
  Sequel.case({ 0 => 0 },
    count_distinct(:homework_results__id).cast(Float) /
      (count_distinct(:assigned_lessons__id) * users_count),
    count_distinct(:assigned_lessons__id),
  )
end

def users_count
  DB["#{schema}__users".to_sym].select { count(id) }.where(year_id: year.id)
end

def count_distinct(column)
  Sequel.function(:count, column).distinct
end
```

Ideas for improving this code are accepting... )